# Singleton for multiple uses?

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, singleton

I am developing an android application in which I can/allowed to use only one instance of MediaPlayer(Singleton instance).

```
static MediaPlayer mp;
public static MediaPlayer getMediaPlayer() {
  if (mp == null) {
     mp = new MediaPlayer();
  }

  return mp;
}
```

Now This activity can be called for two purposes

1. from within application (Say ABC)
2. from any other application (say XYZ) for preview

This instance of mediaplayer is supposed to play either video or audio.
So I have created a class which handles request(parameterized constructor to check for audio instance needed or video instance needed) and based on request, it creates required instance.

But the problem arises when Within application user is playing an audio file and user launched other application (XYZ) and requested to play video.

Now I am storing MediaPlayer's previous state (like which file it was playing and current position etc) and releasing MediaPlayer to be used for XYZ application for Video Playing. And once user stops playing video, ABC resumes playing audio file based on the stored instance.

So is this the right approach? Or I need to do modify the architecture of this task?

Please suggest w.r.t. design patterns

Comment: The way you coded your singleton either won't work at all, or is sub optimal.  Please show us the code for what this singleton is going to be doing.  You are missing an explicit private constructor, and Java will insert a default _public_ constructor.

Comment: Ohh yes, I was just writing a proto code for visual here. The code mentioned here is not exact. But the class is implemented properly

Comment: Please show us the actual code you are using.

Comment: Why you are not using Player in the Service? You can bind service to activity and start playing audio for example. When the user opens your activity from another app, you just need to check that service is working and bind it again to activity to start playing a video. Also it allows you to contorol player's state and you no need to use player as singleton.

Answer (score 1):

Using singletons in Android for state persistance is something to be careful about.

Mabye you should investigate the activity lifecycle to understand in which cases you can loose the singleton instance (and therefore all the data stored inside it).

[Here is some information](https://medium.com/@davethomas_9528/please-dont-use-singletons-to-persist-state-on-android-7bac9bc78b29)

For instance when your app is running in the background, the cellphone can ask for memory and kill the instance of your singleton.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example Singleton that I would try:

```
public class MediaPlayer{


        private static MediaPlayer instance = new MediaPlayer();

        public static MediaPlayer getInstance() {
                return MediaPlayer.instance;
        }

}
```

Now you have a scenario in which you can create objects based on the getInstance() method which can only reference the same object which will ensure your singleton pattern. I tested it and attempted to make objects from this singleton pattern:

```
MediaPlayer t1 = MediaPlayer.getInstance();
MediaPlayer t2 = MediaPlayer.getInstance();
System.out.println(t1.equals(t2));
```

result:

```
true
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but my question is not about how to implement Singleton. It's about the approach. Suggestion about if there is any other better approach for this kind of problem.